# Compute $\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz$, where $f(z)=\frac {ze^{\pi z}}{z^4-16}+ze^{\frac \pi z}$ where $\gamma:9x^2+y^2=9$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Compute $\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz$, where $f(z)=\frac {ze^{\pi z}}{z^4-16}+ze^{\frac \pi z}$ where $\gamma:9x^2+y^2=9$ Using the residue theorem.

I don't know how to start this, first I thought about parametrizing this curve as: $x=\frac 13\cos\theta$ and $y=\sin\theta$ but I don't know how this would help me.. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The curve $\gamma$ (directed counterclockwise) is an ellipse having the poles $\pm2i$ of the first part in its interior, but not the poles $\pm2$. For the first part of the integrand it is therefore sufficient to compute the residues at $\pm2i$, using standard computational methods (no computing of line integrals).

The second part of the integrand has an essential singularity at $0$, but the Laurent expansion
$$z\,e^{\pi/z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\pi^k\over k!}\,z^{1-k}$$
is convergent in the full punctured $z$-plane. The residue at $0$ can then be immediately read off.

Comment: So I have the complex numbers $z_{1,2} = \pm 2i$ and I can just say that $x=0$ and $y = \pm2$ and check if it's in the curve, right?